# What is the word for someone who can quickly identify the root or underlying cause/motivation?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for someone who has an ability to observe/experience anothers actions and words and then quickly identify the root or underlying cause/motivation for those words and actions?

Comment: I don't think there is such a word.

Answer (score 2):

**"perspicacious"** (adj)

- able to judge quickly and correctly what people and situations are really like. [words in a sentence](http://wordsinasentence.com/perspicacious-in-a-sentence/)
- having keen mental perception and understanding; discerning [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/perspicacious)

> - Although the detective was a perspicacious woman, she was not able to identify the killer’s motive.
> - The perspicacious salesman earned a great living because he knew how to read his customers.

Comment: How do you like that? Never heard of it. It would probably be a lot more popular if it was easier to pronounce. (Guess I'll stick with "intuitive", for now.)

Comment: “Insightful” might do, if you want a more common word, though it has a broader meaning. “Perspicacious” is better.